# Exercise in floating point arithmetics. How large power can we get?

Tags: numerical-methods, arithmetic, computer-science, floating-point

Say I have some polynomial

$$P(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_kx^k$$

and double precision floating point numbers with mantissa part $53$ bits and exponent part $11$ bits.

What is the largest magnitude of $x$ I can have if I want to evaluate a polynomial of say, order $64$ and all $c_k\in[-1,1]$?

Comment: I guess you are missing some clarification. You can evaluate the polynomial to the maximum $x$ allowed, it will just not yield the right result as the first power of $x$ will overflow. You could also reason that if `floax_max` is the maximum storable double, then `float_max^(1/64)` is the maximum $x$ so the highest power can be computed, but the sums could also crumble. However, if you pick a not so smaller value,  the lower powers of $x$ may fall below the numeric precision of the higher powers. You might also want to use Horner's rule, which changes part of this reasoning.

Comment: Very good observation @Mefitico.

Comment: @Mefitico feel free to make a more detailed answer if you want to.

Comment: Notice that there is a limitation on two factors: Representing the power value(answered below) and the value resulting from raising the power. The later is the same as the earlier if x=1, but for values other than x=1 and zero, it has a significant effect.

Comment: @NoChance I am aware of this fact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming IEEE754 double representation (so there is a sign bit on exponent and mantissa), the largest $P$ is $\approx 2^{2^{11-1}}=2^{1024}$, so $x^{64}\approx 2^{1024}$ and hence $x\approx 2^{16}=65536$.  This ignores all subtleties about precision of the result depending on the machine implementation, order of operations, etc.

Comment: Yep I was looking for this bound. It is true as you say and also as Mefitico that accurate calculations depend on lots of other stuff. But you mention the upper limit of what we will be able to represent.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using a single word to extend the representational range of IEEE arithmetic.   This eliminates the barrier you have given. The condition number of the polynomial is the issue. Compensated arithmetic can help, but little can be done if the input is not exact.